# How to get ProductID for provider hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

There is `ProductID` mentioned in the `AppManifest.xml` as a GUID. How can I get that ID using Client object model?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is impossible. 
You can pass it as query string parameter (hard-coded).